# MySQL: where (if value exists other then 0 - select value; otherwise, select 0)

Tags: php, mysql, sql, subquery

In where clause of mysql, "where userID = SOME_VALUE; if SOME_VALUE not found  - select 0".

How to?

I tried conditional subselect, which works, but is rather complex:

```
    "SELECT * FROM table_descriptors
    WHERE
    tTable = :table_obj_table 
    AND approvalTable = :approval_table 
    AND (
    CASE WHEN
        IFNULL(( FIND_IN_SET( :user_id2, 
        ( SELECT GROUP_CONCAT(userID) FROM table_descriptors
        WHERE tTable = :table_obj_table2
        AND approvalTable = :approval_table2
        ) ) ), 0) = 0
        THEN userId = '0'
        ELSE userId = :user_id
    END

    ) LIMIT 1";
```

The subselect group_concats user ids and if user id is NOT found in set - select userId = 0. Otherwise, select current user id. IFNULL transforms NULL to 0, just in case.

It works, but is there any other "easy" scenario without "hard" subselect?

Comment: I think sample data and desired results would help.  I don't see what `select 0` means in the context of your query.

Comment: Take a look at MySQL coalesce function

Comment: Hi. You are not clear. Please use more sentences, phrases & words so that you actually say what you mean. Don't write sentence fragments about code fragments. Don't put words in quotes unless you are quoting. It doesn't make something unclear clear, it just lets you pretend to yourself that you were clear when you know you weren't. Please read & act on [mcve].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If I understand correctly, you want user id 0 when the user id does not exist.  If so, you can use a simpler query:

```
SELECT td.*
FROM table_descriptors td
WHERE td.tTable = :table_obj_table AND
      td.approvalTable = :approval_table AND
      td.userId  IN (0, :user_id)
ORDER BY (td.userId = 0) DESC
LIMIT 1;
```

Comment: this does not work, unfortunately, because if 0 found first - that is it, search for possible :user_id is over. I need a definite result like "if :user_id not present among values - select 0". Zero is just a default value.

Comment: @bbe . . . Huh?  You comment doesn't make any sense.  If any other value is present, then this will not return `0`.  Do you see the `ORDER BY`?

Comment: @GordonLinoff, I mean, "if table_descriptors for :user_id not found in the table, than read table_descriptors for user_id = 0". There are plenty of table_descriptors for various users. So, I need first: check if descriptors for current user are available; if not - read default descriptors.

Comment: @bbe . . . And that is what this code does.  Have you tried it?

Comment: @GordonLinoff, yes, I tried. DB read goes in unpredicted order, and once it finds either 0 or :user_id, it stops. So, 0 was easily selected even though :user_id value was also present.

Comment: @bbe . . . That is not how the code in the question works.  All rows that match the `WHERE` clause are then sorted.  The ones with the values of `0` are put at the end of the list . . . then the first row is chosen.  That should be one other than `0` if such a value exists.

Comment: @GordonLinoff, works, thanx! Except, what is the meaning of ORDER BY (td.userId = 0) ? i.e., =0 part? I put just ORDER BY td.userId DESC - this works

Comment: @bbe . . . In MySQL, boolean expressions are treated as numbers in a numeric context, with "1" for true and "0" for false.  The `order by . . . desc` puts the true values before the false values.